# Difference between ThreeDBorderWindow and SingleBorderWindow

Tags: wpf, xaml, window-style

In WPF XAML, `WindowStyle` can be **None**, **SingleBorderWindow**, **ThreeDBorderWindow**, **ToolWindow**.

I tried the options myself and also looked into [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx), yet I cannot tell any difference visually between **ThreeDBorderWindow** and **SingleBorderWindow**. The "ThreeDBorder" looks just as 2-D as SingelBorder. What are their difference?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to switch to **Windows Classic** theme to see the difference. If you are using a "modern" theme like **Windows 7** there is no difference.

Below you have the `SingleBorderWindow` to the left and `ThreeDBorderWindow` to the right when using **Windows Classic** theme on my computer. (The innermost gray border is from a control in the window and is not part of the window border.)

[image: SingleBorderWindow]
[image: ThreeDBorderWindow]

The "3D" border has an inside highlight that I guess gives it a raised or three dimensional look.

Comment: That is really a very catchy thing. +1

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that when a `ThreeDBorderWindow` is when maximised, the edge of the window doesn't touch the edge of the monitor, there is a one pixel gap between the window edge and last pixel where the windows behind can been seen, I've noticed this using windows 10